# Can I activate browser search with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to request a page for an intranet application with the option to by default activate the browser's document search function as in:

```
//server/docsite/index.php?page=5522&search=401-01-011
```

I want the search argument to be sensed and activate the search dialog, similar to pressing clrl-f and typing 401-01-011. Is it possible with javascript?

Comment: Maybe you could simulate the behavior with [`mark.js`](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js)

Comment: you can use the `window` function `find(yourString)`, but there are some [limitations][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Comment: @Guedes, excellent!

Comment: @SanDroid. To use inline links type: `[text](http://link.com)`